# Identify Mystery Backup File - Possibly cPanel?

Tags: backup-restoration, cpanel

A client contacted interested in getting his website back up and running after taking it down ~4 years ago and wanted to know if I still had a backup anywhere. Being a digital pack rat, I did!

But I don't know what the backup was made with. The backup file is labeled "backup_file" with no file extension and also as a ".autofck" file next to it. I suspect it was from a cPanel full site back up but don't have a way to tell.

It is too big to just be a SQL dump of his site (500 MB, it was a tiny forum).

The host he is moving to doesn't have cPanel. Is there anyway to verify this is a cPanel back up and if so anyway to convert it to a more open backup format?

Is there any sort forensics I can conduct to figure out what program might have made it?

Comment: `file` says...?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, figured it out. Opened it up in ultra edit:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.14  Distrib 5.5.38-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: x
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.38-MariaDB
```

It is a SQL back up.